# How to control maximum falling speed in physics simulation?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I've made some scripts of falling objects to print z coordinate over time (at every frame) so I obtain z-t, vel-t and accel-t charts (vel = dz/dt and accel = dvel/dt) with different damping translation in order to find which terminal velocity corresponds to every damping translation coefficient.

I've been trying this set up until I found a numerical precision cap as I was turning damping closer to 1. At 0.9999999 blender reads as if it was a damping translation value of 1. I want a higher number because it still moves too quick for my simulation. The slowest I could get is ~0.7 m/s with a damping of 0.999999.

I want to simulate objects of high mass, several Tons at low speed, less than 1 m/s. I want to build a breakwater with concrete armor units. The velocity I'm working with right now should be 1 m/s with a damping translation of 0.99998. But I want to get It lower.

How I can lower the speed? Is there any way to change some kind of scale so I can go further to lower the falling velocity?

Any other ideas?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just curious, what version of Blender are you using, and how are you getting the z-coordinate during the animation?

Comment: you could fake it and change Blender's idea of G or add an upward force to counteract G, I suppose.  Or you could try to simulate atmospheric pressure using an upward force to represent the drag coefficient but I don't think Blender models that accurately.

Comment: 2.91, one of the latest if not the latest one. To read coordinates I use matrix_world transform of a pair of vertices of the object that are oposite one to another to get its x,y,z coordinates and I obtain the middle point which is the center of mass.
vertices = obj.data.vertices; verts = [obj.matrix_world @ vert.co for vert in vertices] something like that I have on my script

Comment: Another idea I've had is soimething like linking the object to a cable and I keyframe the positionof one end of the cable so it follows as long as the cable doesnt stretch.

Comment: you could turn down gravity ;) or lower the simulation speed in rigid body settings...or use wind force e.g. if you set the strength high enough it lowers the speed until it rises up...

Comment: If I delete gravity how objects will interact? I want to simulate objects that are placed at a certain velocity but they have too much momentum right now. Gravity is the force that rules the behaviour of my simulation, how objects will rest on top of another? I'm looking to drop them at like 0.1 m/s.

Comment: i didn't write delete...turn down...so just lower it. e.g. to -1 instead of -9.81. you can change it here: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxpSi.png